# Try With Resources. Refactor Sonar

Tags: java, sonar, java-7

Estoy revisando mi código en sonarqube para mejorarlo y me he encontrado con una alerta en el siguiente código:

```
  try { 
           os = new FileOutputStream(file); 
           os.write((byte[]) response.get(Constants.CONTENT)); 
       } catch (Exception e) { 
           log.error(e.getMessage(),e);
           error = true;
       }
       finally {
           if (os != null) {
               os.close();
           }
       }
```

El error de sonarqube dice lo siguiente: Try-with-resources should be used [image: Error de sonarqube]

La compliant solution me marca que es algo similar a esto:

```
try (
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)
  ) {
  return br.readLine();
}
catch (...) {}
```

¿Podéis explicarme por qué a priori es mejor así que con un finally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los motivos son sencillos:

- Cuanto menos código necesitemos escribir, más legible será. Esto es especialmente cierto cuando el código que nos ahorramos es para la gestión de errores o tareas que no son específicamente relacionadas con nuestro negocio/dominio.
- Si no necesitamos escribir ese código, no se nos puede olvidar escribirlo ni lo podemos escribir incorrectamente, luego hay menos errores potenciales a revisar.

Tu código se quedaría así:

```java
try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file)) { 
    os.write((byte[]) response.get(Constants.CONTENT)); 
} catch (Exception e) { 
    log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    error = true;
}
```

No necesitas que el stream (la variable `os`) sea alcanzable fuera del bloque `try`, por lo que puedes declararla dentro y borrar todo el finally, lo que también ayuda un poco más a la legibilidad.